# VBA Code MsgBox if 2 criteria for each row in table

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have a code that looks up 2 different cells and displays a pop up every time both cells have certain criteria, however it only does it for that specific row.

I'm looking for a way to have 1 code that will look up every pair of cells on each row and evaluate them independently.

Tried changing the ranges but obviously that creates a long code, I'm sure there is a better way but my knowledge is limited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
         If (Range("A2").Value = "Text1") And Range("B2").Value > ### Then MsgBox "Message"

End If

End Sub
```

The code should look at the entire table of 200 rows and ideally keep looking if the table grows larger for specific criteria on each row, all `A2` and `B2`, `A3` and `B3` and so on.
Currently it only looks at the cells I selected and the only solution I can think of is to copy paste and change the ranges on each new piece of the code.

Thank you!

Comment: `If Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = "Text1" And Range("B" & Target.ROW).Value > ### Then MsgBox "Message"`
`

Comment: Also you may want to use `Target.Cells.CountLarge` instead of `.Count`? Please see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: What you describe needs a For ... Next loop. Look it up at MSDN or where they teach. Logically that doesn't make sense in a Change event, however, because only one item was changed at a time and you don't need to check those that weren't changed because they have been checked before. To create a dynamic range look at Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @Variatus: When you paste on multiple cells in the relevant range then the change happens in those as well. But the `Target.Cells.CountLarge/Target.Cells.Count` will negate it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, that was perfect! thank you so much! you fixed my problem sir.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over columns A and B:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LookUpWithMessageBox()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "column A criteria" And Cells(i, 2).Value = "column B criteria" Then MsgBox Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        'Calculate table last row
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Set rng to search (FROM Column A row 2 TO Column B row 5)
        Set rngTable = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 2))
        'Check if tha target included in the table
        If Not Intersect(Target, rngTable) Is Nothing Then
            'Check if the target and the cell next to it are equal
            If Target.Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                'if both cells are equal meesage with there address will appear
                MsgBox "Cells " & Replace(Target.Offset(0, -1).Address, "$", "") & " and " & Replace(Target.Address, "$", "") & " are the same!"
            End If

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Sheet structure:

[image]